# Two pass report?

Tags: ms-access, report

Using MS Access 2013 I created a table to track load data for a trucking company using teams of 2 drivers per load trip.  The table stores driver1 and driver2 and the total miles for each load trip.  Both drivers get paid for the same miles per trip.  I need to print a report listing each individual driver and the total miles from each load he participated in. Since each driver may be driver1 on some loads and driver2 on others I'm not sure how to approach such a report.  I could print 2 reports, one for driver1 and one for driver2 and then manually add the driver totals together but I would like to do this in one report listing each driver and the total miles he would be paid for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union query as the source for your report. `SELECT Driver1, Miles FROM tblTrips UNION Driver2, Miles FROM tblTrips`

Comment: Bob is Driver1 for a trip of 100  miles.  Bob is Driver2 for another trip of 100  miles.  `UNION` returns distinct rows, so those 2 trips would result in only one row.  Use `UNION ALL` to preserve duplicate rows.

Comment: That worked perfect and it was so simple. Thanks a million!